# Floating divs with different height, fill empty space

Tags: css, css-float

I have 3 floating divs (second /green/ is taller than third /blue/) and while viewport is narrower I would like to last (third) div would take (fill) empty space below first div.

[image: preview]

I could achieve this by using media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 750px) 
{
    #third
    {
        margin-top: -100px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) 
{
    #third
    {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2G5J/15/ How to achive this effect without media queries (I don't know divs height). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Without changing the source order you would need javascript, I think - http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: look like this http://jsfiddle.net/s2G5J/18/

Comment: Pawan Lakhara - it is completly wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="first"></div>
        <div id="second"></div>
        <div id="third"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#container
{
    max-width: 500px;
}

#first, #second, #third
{
    width: 250px;    
}

#first, #third
{
    float: left;    
    height: 100px;
}

#second
{
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
}

#first
{
    background-color: yellow;    
}

#second
{
    background-color: lime;
}

#third
{
    background-color: blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : *500px*) 
{
    #container > div
    {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

You probably notice how the lime box floats to the right for a while after getting the limit. That's just because of the margins and paddings of the body and the things around it. Just set number surrounded with asterisks according to the elements around it (516px is the number for jsfiddle and default margins and paddings).

Comment: I would like to have solution without media queries. To clarify: when viewport is wider than 750px, all 3 divs must be display in one line (side by side)

Comment: I don't think you can do that without media queries. You'd need javascript, which I can show if you want to. If you want them side by side make another with `min-width: 750` and float everything left