# 3 divs with float: left > floating issues

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

how can I display the given html structure while all divs has float: left ?

```
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
<div id="d3"></div>
```

[image: div layout]

Comment: will need `float:right` on the second http://jsfiddle.net/metq1sh5/

Comment: do you search simple solution for plain filling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117376/floating-divs-with-different-height-fill-empty-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i did it.

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline;
  clear: none;
  float: left;
}
#container {
  max-width: 390px;
  display: block;
}
#d1 {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
#d2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}
#d3 {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="d1"></div>
  <div id="d2"></div>
  <div id="d3"></div>
</div>
```

Just needs the second element to be floated right within a container div.

Comment: can you to scale this solution for 7 divs different heights?

Comment: Im not too sure off the top of my head, give it a try and see how it works and affects the display. Copy the above code to codepen and see how it goes.

Comment: 7 is just a number.. I just think, is there any pure-CSS solution to fill screen with any(dinamic changeable) number of diffs... And it's another question :)

Comment: Sadly i don't think there is unless you get exceedingly creative with the css running it and know exactly how big each div is going to be etc which just wont run well with responsiveness. Your best bet is really to stick with a JS way of running it say through masonryJS (http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You put a container div around div one and three

```css
#container
{
  width:80%;
  float:left;
}
#three
{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  background-color:blue;
  height:600px;
}
#one, #two
{
  background-color:green;
  margin:10px 10px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">1</div>
  <div id="two">2</div>
 </div>
<div id="three">3</div>
```

Comment: This simply creates 3 divs stacked in a column, not the format op specified. The css doesn't even effect the divs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this answer is vague, but it's only as vague as your question.  An example of how this could be done is below:

```css
#container {
  float: left;
}
#d1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
#d2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
#d3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="d1"></div>
  <div id="d2"></div>
</div>
<div id="d3"></div>
```

I hope you get some inspiration . . .